How to make conditional statements using selectors?
Hello I need to make a conditional statement as follow with python
if (expect(page0.get_by_text("text expect")).to_be_visible()):
    page0.get_by_role("button", name="Delete").click()     
else:
    page0.get_by_role("link", name="Sign up").click()

Is there a way to do this? I didn't found anything in the Playwright documentation.

The suggested dupe answers the question, but taking a step back, it's generally best to avoid conditions in tests--conditions are an antipattern in browser automation--99% of the time they're not the best solution to your problem.
